# Why is no text shown within the JOptionPane when my paintComponent method is called?

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I'm trying to make a message dialog appear when the user enters an invalid input.

When I try to use `null` as the location for the dialog, the dialog appears correctly when 0 or a negative number is entered, but there's no title or text in the dialog.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // draw lines

    endY = getHeight(); // bottom
    endX = getWidth(); // right side
    Input = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());

    if (Input > 0 ) {

        for (int beginY = getHeight() / 2; beginY <= endY; beginY += Input) {
            g.drawLine(0, beginY, endX, beginY);
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please do not enter 0 or a negative number.", "Wrong input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I've tried using my `JFrame` object which has been declared and initialized in a different class as the first parameter and this works.

However, I want to be able to use this code in my `JPanel` class in the `paintComponent` method so I can add if/else logic to it when drawing the lines.

Answer (score 0):

> The paintComponent method is called whenever something in the AWT EDT (Abstract Window Toolkit Event Dispatching Thread)
>   thinks the component needs to be repainted. That method is
>   called often and often at moments you didn't expect it to be called.
>   So, don't show a JOptionPane in the body of that method. You have to
>   take that logic out of the method and show it when needed.

You could do something like this, but this is not a good programming practice:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (canPaint) {
        // Do some painting if we can
        // Lets say an error occurred:
        // If the dialog is shown over the component then the component will
        // be redrawn. Now, we don't want this code to loop, so we set a
        // flag to control the "loop".
        canPaint = false;

        // Now we tell the AWT event queue that we want to show the message
        // whenever it get's a chance, because the Dialog won't be drawn
        // properly if it's called here.
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showWarning();
            }
        });
    }
}

void showWarning() {
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Syntax Error : ", "Incorrect user input", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

**But in general never do programming logic inside the paintComponent method!**

For more information see this post: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/26110-joptionpane-when-called-inside-paintcomponent-method.html